# Inserting an SQL record if one doesn't exist with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've done a lot of looking around for this question, and some of them seem like they could work but are just a bit off.

I'm trying to get this record to be added into a database if the same record **doesn't** already exists.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pmd_OrderData (UserID, ProductID, ProductName, ProductPrice, ProductAmount) VALUES ($UserID, $ProductID, 'Test Product', 100, 1)");
```

**NOTE: There is not a single unique column in this table, 2 columns together make a unique record. e.g: 1 UserID can have 2 ProductIDs, 1 ProductID can have 2 UserIDs at any one time.**

I've tried this:

```
--(INSERT QUERY)-- WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pmd_OrderData WHERE UserID=$UserID AND ProductID=$ProductID
```

I've seen things about `IGNORE` and `REPLACE` but didn't fully understand them.

Now, it seems that most methods use unique (Primary) keys to work things like this, so I'm not 100% sure how any of them will work for me (I'm sure there's something that will).

Comment: Try change from "INSERT INTO" to "INSERT IGNORE INTO"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sql
INSERT INTO pmd_OrderData (UserID, ProductID, ProductName, ProductPrice, ProductAmount) 
SELECT $UserID, $ProductID, 'Test Product', 100, 1
from dual where not exists
(
  select 1 FROM pmd_OrderData 
  WHERE UserID = $UserID AND ProductID = $ProductID
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works well! I'm not accepting it as the answer as another one has given me an idea >:D

Comment: After a few trials and tribulations this is the answer that has worked best for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there's a `unique` key in the table to prevent duplicates. Then use the syntax `INSERT IGNORE INTO` on your queries. This will make them fail silently in case there are duplicates.

Comment: This data won't be stored for very long, it's a temporary thing for the current session so I shouldn't think there will be any duplicates that cause errors, but thank you!

Comment: @Mallander If there are duplicates in a table with a `unique` key, there will be an error. This is however the easiest way to prevent any duplicate entries, and the `IGNORE` keyword will make sure that error is not thrown to the user at least.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method for doing this is `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO pmd_OrderData (UserID, ProductID, ProductName, ProductPrice, ProductAmount)
    VALUES ($UserID, $ProductID, 'Test Product', 100, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UserId = VALUES(UserId);
```

However, you need a unique key for this.  I believe the unique key for this table is `UserId, ProductId`, so define:

```
create unique index idx_pmd_OrderData_2 on pmd_OrderData(UserId, ProductId);
```

The advantage of `on duplicate key update` over `insert ignore` is that the latter will ignore all errors.  The first handles the duplication directly but will still produce other, unrelated errors.